# List ALL Taxonomy Terms with Views

Tags: views

I am trying to figure out how to use views to list out ALL my taxonomy terms that are grouping node titles.
Example:

Taxonomy Term 1
- Node Title 1
- Node Title 2

Taxonomy Term 2
- Node Title 3

Taxonomy Term 3
-Message: There are currently no Node titles at this time, please check back

Taxonomy Term 4
- Node Title 4
- Node Title 5

Answer (score 4):

1. Create a 'taxonomy term' view
2. Add 'Taxonomy term: Content with term' as a relationship (don't make it required, otherwise unused terms won't show up)
3. Add two fields, 'Taxonomy term:Name'(mark this excluded from display since we will group them in the next step) and 'Content:Title'
4. Go to Format settings: set 'grouping field Nr.1' to 'Taxonomy term:Name'
5. Now you get the data you want, you can use your preferred approach to style them.